# How to send to the controller a parameter value like `params[:user][:delete]` using a `check_box_tag`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, parameters, checkbox

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and I am tring to send to the controller a parameter value like `params[:user][:delete]` using a `check_box_tag`.

*At this time* in my form I have:

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_fiels :name %>
  ...
  <%= check_box_tag(:delete, nil, false) %>

  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

that send the `params[:user]` (the user hash) and `params[:delete]`.

*I would like to* have `params[:user][:delete]` instead of `params[:delete]`. **How to change the `check_box_tag` arguments to do that**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

```
<%= check_box_tag('user[delete]', nil, false) %>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to do it inside of a block to scope it like so:

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.check_box :delete %>:
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: In the question I did not write all the code for the form, but, obviously, in my view file there is and it works for '<%= check_box_tag(:delete, nil, false) %>'. I need just to know what I write: send to the controller a parameter value like params[:user][:delete] instead of params[:delete]. Thanks anyway.

Comment: i am not sure i follow, can you provide any other details?

Comment: why are you not using the check_box_tag and not the f.check_box method like your other inputs?

Answer (score 1):

also

```
<%= check_box('user', 'delete', nil, false) %>
```